# Using reflection to instantiate a class without running its constructor

Tags: c#, reflection, constructor

Is it possible to do this?

I have a class with validation logic in the constructor. For general use I want to enforce this constructor.

However, when deserializing the so said class, I want to be able to bypass that validation logic and simply reserve the memory space without running any construction routine (like malloc in c++).The properties will then be mapped manually using reflection, after the object has been instantiated.  Is this possible in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject.aspx)